# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in cocos2d-x v3.5

Tags: cocos2d-x

How do we watch for stuff like UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in cocos2d-x?

Like this order:

1. This needs to be multiplatform
2. Else, delegate to each platform and force it to implement this in it's own way aka bridging?

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.cpp, there is `AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()` and `AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()`. For now it's enough for me to hook into those.

Otherwise there is something called EVentDispatcher whose singelton can be fetched through the Director instance,, but I'm not sure that can be used for the above events.